# What tool(s) can I use to use a .faa file to feed into JSMol?

Tags: fasta, protein-structure, sequence-annotation, pdb, perl

JSMol, the molecular modelling software, requires PDB file format to work and render the graphics. Currently, I am writing an annotation software - backend in Perl - that takes in a .faa file (fasta amino acids). Is there any way or tool out there that can easily convert to a PDB file? Many of the tools out there do not seem to give what I need.

My workflow so far:

input.fna -> Bakta -> bakta.faa -> **covert tool** -> proteins.pdb -> JSMol

Essentially, a tool exists called pdb2fasta that takes a pdb file and converts to a fasta file but can’t seem to find a proper tool that does it the other way around.

Comment: Or do you just want an unfolded sequence of amino acids (as atoms and bonds)? In any case, you will need something that generates those coordinates, even if just as a linear 'model' of a chain

Comment: Would you happen to have any ideas what I could use to do that? @gilleain

Comment: @HarishPrabhakar That is an exceptionally difficult problem for a variety of reasons. there is not an obvious way to translate linear AA sequence into three-dimensional structure. You may have heard of [alphafold](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03819-2), which uses neural nets to more or less solve the problem. But you have to understand that this is a stochastic and error-prone prediction!